# Calculate min past midnight in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I'm trying to calculate number of minutes past mid night using smarty. I can get the current time ... but how do i get the difference from mid-night. How to i create a date/time object which represent 12:00 midnight?

Comment: Which version of smarty? 2 or 3?

Comment: This isn't something you can really do in Smarty without resorting to the `{php}` function, ideally this should be done in PHP then passed to the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a timestamp to construct a DateTime for midnight:

$midnight = strtotime("0:00");
$dt = new DateTime("@$midnight");

Then to find the time difference, you can use the date_diff function:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 0):

I agree with John C, this logic does not belong on smarty. So i ended up writing it in php, and then invoking the function in smarty. To get the midnight time i did following

```
$midnightTime = new DateTime();        
$midnightTime -> setTime(0,0,0);   
midnightTime->getTimestamp()
```

and then used the suggestion by Greg to calculate the diff using date_diff.